# How do I split a text by 4 newlines in a file with Bash?

Tags: bash, loops, file, cut

Given a text file with multiple lines, I would like to seperate this text of blabla everytime 4 newlines turn up in a Bash script. I had attempted to use cut, but cut does not accept \n (newline) as a delimiter? So I want to end up with 3 files of blabla. Is there a way to do some kind of loop?

```
blabla
blabla




blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla




blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
blabla
```

cat file.cut | cut -d$'\n\n\n\n' -f1

Comment: `cut` processes the input line-by-line. It does not make sense to look for a newline "inside" a line.

Comment: What does it mean _I would like to seperate this text_ ? How should the output look like?

Comment: What kind of naming scheme do you expect the resulting files to follow?

Comment: If the answer provided offered the guidance you needed, it would be appreciated that you indicated that by clicking on the check-mark next to the Answer below.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly applying the usage of "**cut**" for file splitting, when it was intended for line/record splitting.

Your problem is very much one where [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is most suitable.  The following performs the requested splitting.

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TEST_INPUT="${BASE}.input"

cat >"${TEST_INPUT}" <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
blabla1
blabla2




blabla3
blabla4
blabla5
blabla6




blabla7
blabla8
blabla9
blabla10
blabla11
!EnDoFiNpUt


awk -v prefix="split_file" 'BEGIN{
    ### Establish initial conditions
    ### Counter for empty lines
    counter=0 ;
    ### Counter for output file identifier
    fIndex=1 ;
    ### Define name for output target file
    file=sprintf("%s__%s", prefix, fIndex ) ;
    printf("Directing output to: %s\n", file ) | "cat >&2" ;
}
{
    if( NF == 0 ){
        print $0 | "cat >"file ;
        ### Counter for number of empty lines
        counter++ ;
        if( counter == 4 ){
            ### Action to take if 4th consecutive empty line
            counter=0 ;
            fIndex++ ;
            file=sprintf("%s__%s", prefix, fIndex ) ;
            printf("Directing output to: %s\n", file ) | "cat >&2" ;
        } ;
    }else{
        ### Redirect input line to most recently specified target file
        print $0 | "cat >"file ;
    } ;
}' "${TEST_INPUT}"
```

The above passes **all** empty lines into the output files, because it is simpler than trying to discriminate between passing single empty lines (likely wanted) and the 4-consecutive empty lines (the splitting condition).  Since the 4-line condition will always be at the end of the files, that shouldn't be a real issue and, if necessary, is easily overcome by doing

```
tac ${file} | tail -n +5 | tac >${truncated_file}
```

The form

```
print $0 | "cat >"file
```

may *seems* counter-intuitive, but all lines are indeed appended to the most recent definition of **file**, until that changes.  *It will also overwrite any instance of file from a previous execution of the script.*